# Python 3.6 types: Using variable before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

New way of type/hinting/assignments is cool, but I don't know how to make such a simple thing work:

```
class MyContainer:
    def addMyItem(self, item:MyItem):
        pass

class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, container:MyContainer):
        pass
```

It throw an error: `Using variable 'MyItem' before assignment`.
The best but super ugly workaround I found so far is this:

```
class MyContainer:
    def addMyItem(self, untypeditem):
        item:MyItem=untypeditem
        pass

class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, container:MyContainer):
        pass
```

Please tell me that language with #1 principle `Beautiful is better than ugly` has something better to solve this common typing issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forward references are just strings referring to the name (as it is visible in the module).

```
class MyContainer:
    def addMyItem(self, item: 'MyItem'):
        pass

class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, container: 'MyContainer'):
        pass
```

If you need to import the name from somewhere else (and you only need the name for type checking, or if it might cause a circular import), you can use

```
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from foo import Thing
```

[`TYPE_CHECKING` is true only when a type checker is running (i.e. your code is not being evaluated for execution).](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING)

Comment: can't say is really beautiful, but I just tested and it works! Thank you, dear sir!

Comment: I don't know, I think it's as beautiful as you can get for a dynamic language :) You're welcome!

Comment: typescript is also dynamic, but it works that way. I think this issue is  typically solved via hoisting